Pylint No name 'keras' in module 'tensorflow'
In vscode, when I open terminal I see: (peakInt) (base) me@hostname:/path/to/project
The linter seems to work for everything except for keras. import tensorflow as tf is fine, but from tensorflow import keras shows "no name Keras in module tensorflow"
In the built in terminal, if I enter python and import keras it works fine.
from tensorflow import keras
2024-12-31 16:09:43.092470: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-12-31 16:09:43.115161: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2024-12-31 16:09:43.115186: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2024-12-31 16:09:43.116085: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-12-31 16:09:43.120355: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI AVX512_BF16 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-12-31 16:09:43.486869: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT

